# My code running with Apache poi 3.12 version, now changed to 4.1.2 version. How to set HSSFWorkbook and HSSFCell in CellUtil.setAlignment()

Tags: java, apache-poi

My code running with Apache poi 3.12 version, now changed to 4.1.2 version. How to set HSSFWorkbook and HSSFCell in CellUtil.setAlignment( HSSFCell headingcell, HSSFWorkbook  hwb, CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER); Getting compilation error on this. I need to set both HSSFWorkbook and HSSFCell  into it. Please help me on this. PFB code I am using,

```
      HSSFWorkbook hwb;
      HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet(sheetName);         
        CellStyles cellStyle = new CellStyles();
        HSSFCellStyle labelHeaderOrangeStyle = cellStyle.getHeadingStyleTwo(hwb);
        
        //Sheet Title-Start
        HSSFRow mainHeadingRow = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
        HSSFCell headingcell = mainHeadingRow.createCell(0);
        if(standardReportsFormBean.getDropDownText().equals(StandardReportsConstants.EMPTYSTRING)){
            title += " for ALL options";
        }else{
            title += " for " + standardReportsFormBean.getDropDownValue();
        }
        title += " - Date: " + standardReportsFormBean.getMonthValue() + "-" + standardReportsFormBean.getYearValue();
        headingcell.setCellValue(title);
        headingcell.setCellStyle(labelHeaderOrangeStyle);
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowIndex, rowIndex, 0,StandardReportsConstants.MAXCOLUMNINDEXEXTENSIONS));
    
        CellUtil.setAlignment(headingcell, hwb, CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

Comment: [CellUtil.setAlignment(Cell cell, HorizontalAlignment align)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#setAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment-) -> [HorizontalAlignment.LEFT](/https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/HorizontalAlignment.html#LEFT)

Comment: @AxelRichter  Thanks for your reply ,I have used the same, but in middle parameter HSSFWorkbook hwb is missing in this method, for this at the time of download excel getting issue, my excel sheet is not open. whenever i revert the code , again working fine with Apache poi3.12 version

Comment: Sometimes i tried with this code,
CellStyle stringStyle = hwb.createCellStyle();
   stringStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
but how to add HSSFCell

Comment: Works for me using `CellUtil` as shown in my first comment. Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we are able reproducing your issue.

Comment: @AxelRichter I have used like this,
//   CellUtil.setAlignment(headingcell, hwb, CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
   CellUtil.setAlignment(headingcell, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);

Comment: Secure zip unable one or more temporary file. getting issue at the time of download .xls file